# Konva TextPath: не верно рендерится полукруглый текст

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, webgl

Есть curved text, который рендерится с помощью Konva.TextPath:

```
const konvaText = new Konva.TextPath({
            text: 'Community',
            fontSize: 160,
            fontFamily: 'AgencyFB',
            fill: 'blue',
            stroke: 'yellow',
            strokeThickness: 1,
            align: 'center',
            letterSpacing: 17 * 4,
            data: 'M 31.2 -116 A 416 320 0 1 1 88.4 -108',
        });

konvaText.toImage({
            callback: (sprite) => {

                const pixiSprite = new PIXI.Sprite(new PIXI.Texture(new PIXI.BaseTexture(sprite)));

                const preview = new PIXI.Application({ width: 1500, height: 600 });
                preview.stage.addChild(pixiSprite);
                document.querySelector('body').prepend(preview.view);
            }
        });
```

В браузере шрифт превращается в стандартный times new roman, буквы начинают плясать, весь текст сдвигается, и выглядит это так:

[image]

Самое странное, если постоянно нажимать f5, то примерно 1 случай из 10 заканчивается правильным рендером:

[image]

Вот так добавлял шрифт:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "AgencyFB";
    src: url("assets/fonts/AgencyFB.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

### Вариант [textPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath) SVG

На мой взгляд это проще, чем использовать фреймворки. Хотя бы с той точки зрения, что если будет ошибка в svg, который является основой всех фреймворков для SVG, то фреймворк не поможет.

Стили для шрифта вынесены во внешнюю таблицу стилей CSS. При необходимости они легко меняются. SVG дружит с CSS.

Первый символ текста при  `<textPath  xlink:href="#path"`  автоматически размещается в начале кривой  `#path`  с координатами `d="M 50 350`

Отступ для регулировки положения текста регулируется- `startOffset="11%`

```css
.container {
width:70vw;
height:auto;
}
#txt1 {
font-size:84px;
font-family:  sans-serif;
font-weight: 600;
fill:white;
stroke:red;
stroke-width:1.5;
letter-spacing: 10px ;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 600 300" style="background:#151515" >   
    <path id="path" fill="none"  d="M 50 350 A 200 200 0 0 1 550,350" />
<text id="txt1">   
  <textPath  xlink:href="#path"  startOffset="11%"> COMMUNITY </textPath>
</text>
</svg>
</div>
```

### Вариант с анимацией букв

Используется анимация атрибута `startOffset`, который регулирует отступ первой буквы слова от начала траектории движения

*Для начала анимации кликнете по холсту SVG*

```css
.container {
width:50vw;
height:auto;
}
#txt1 {
font-size:84px;
font-family:  sans-serif;
font-weight: 600;
fill:white;
stroke:red;
stroke-width:1.5;
letter-spacing: 10px ;
vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 600 300" style="background:#151515" >   
    

    <path id="path" fill="none"  d="M 50 350 A 200 200 0 0 1 550,350" />
<text id="txt1"   >  
   
    <textPath  xlink:href="#path"  startOffset="110%"> COMMUNITY 
       <animate
         begin="svg1.click"
         dur="4s"
         repeatCount="5"
         attributeName="startOffset"
         values="110%;12%;12%;110%"
     fill="freeze"
     restart="whenNotActive/>
    </textPath>
</text>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: @Олег Верушкин Если ответ вам был полезен, не забудьте отметить его, как решение